# Getting latest version of Android from sdkmanager automatically

Tags: bash

I was trying to make a bash script to automatically install flutter and android sdk without Android Studio.

I managed to get the latest version of build-tools using the following sequence

```bash
btversion=`sdkmanager --list | tac | sed "/build-tools/q" | tac | sed -n 1p`
btversion=${btversion%     *}
btversion=${btversion:2}
```

I am trying to do something similar to install `platforms;android-%version%`, except doing something like this lead me to a dead end:

```bash
sdkmanager --list | tac | sed "/platforms;android-[0-9]+/g"
```

The `[0-9]+` filter is necessary as packages such as `platforms;android-TiramisuPrivacySandbox` show up in the list.

I would like to know what would be a better filter. For reference, this is how the output of sdkmanager --list sort of looks like

```
  platforms;android-27                                                                     | 3            | Android SDK Platform 27                                             
  platforms;android-28                                                                     | 6            | Android SDK Platform 28                                             
  platforms;android-29                                                                     | 5            | Android SDK Platform 29                                             
  platforms;android-30                                                                     | 3            | Android SDK Platform 30                                             
  platforms;android-31                                                                     | 1            | Android SDK Platform 31                                             
  platforms;android-32                                                                     | 1            | Android SDK Platform 32                                             
  platforms;android-33                                                                     | 2            | Android SDK Platform 33
```

Comment: how should look your expected result for sdkmanager? add it to your question

Comment: just "platforms;android-33"

sorry for the late reply, I did not receive an email when you commented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be like

```
sdkmanager --list | egrep -i 'platforms;android-[0-9]{2}' | tac | head -n 1 | sed 's/\(platforms;android-[0-9]\+\).*/\1/'
```

or

```
sdkmanager --list | egrep -i 'platforms;android-[0-9]{2}' | sed 's/\(platforms;android-[0-9]\+\).*/\1/' | tail -1
```